# Extra substitution when rendering a tagged template literal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals, tagged-templates

I just started to use template literals and tagged template literals. But I'm running into a problem when trying to render a template literal because it renders an extra substitution that I can wonder where it comes from.

This is what I have tried:

*My data*

```
var data = {
    login: "john_12",
    name: "John",
    bio: "developer",
    email: "jdev@mail.com"
}
```

*My tag function*

```
function replaceNullData(strings, ...parts) { 
     var checkedMarkup = ""; 
     strings.forEach((string, index) => { 
         if (!parts[index]){ 
             parts[index] = "data no available"; 
         } 
         checkedMarkup += string + parts[index]; 
     }); 

     return checkedMarkup; 
 }
```

*My template literal*

```
var summaryMarkup = replaceNullData`
         <div>
             <p>Username: ${data.login}</p>
         </div>
         <div>
             <p>Name: ${data.name}</p>
         </div>
         <div>
             <p>Bio: ${data.bio}/<p>
         </div>
         <div>
             <p>Email: ${data.email}</p>
         </div>
     `;
```

Now, if I do `console.log(summaryMarkup);`, I obtain this:

```
     <div> 
         <p>Username: john_12</p> 
     </div> 
     <div> 
         <p>Name: John</p> 
     </div> 
     <div> 
         <p>Bio: developer/<p> 
     </div> 
     <div> 
         <p>Email: jdev@mail.com</p> 
     </div> 
 data no available <------- THIS IS WHAT SHOULDN'T APPEAR
```

There is an extra "data no available" at the end. It's like the tag function received 6 `parts` (substitution or expressions) instead of 5.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `strings.length === parts.length + 1`, always.

Comment: Consider this template literal: `\`${foo}\``. When you pass it to your tag function, `strings` will be `['', '']` and parts will be `[foo]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `parts.length` is the length you expected, but notice you're iterating `strings`, not `parts`. `strings.length === parts.length + 1`, so you're accessing `parts` out-of-bounds. Iterate `parts` instead and append the last string outside the iteration:

```
function replaceNullData(strings, ...parts) { 
    var checkedMarkup = ""; 
    parts.forEach((part, index) => {
        if (part == null) { // because false, 0, NaN, and '' should be "available"
            part = "data not available";
        }

        checkedMarkup += strings[index] + part;
    });

    return checkedMarkup + strings[strings.length - 1]; // manually append last string
}
```